# WPF button with external background image

Tags: c#, wpf

I know a lot of people asked about background image of a WPF button and it is possible, but I would like to ask how to add external image ( from Internet ) to the button's background . Is there a way ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the button's background explicitly using an ImageBrush:

```
<Button Content="Hello">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: After clicking the button, the button's interfaces turns from background image to nothing and the revert one in a loop, how can we solve it ?

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer is correct, and for changing the background in C# codes:

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(IMAGE_URL_HERE));
brush1.ImageSource = image;
button1.Background = brush1;
```

Both are correct.

Comment: How can I read the BitmapImage from ImageBrush from Button Background? it returns SolidBrush instead.